# CSS grid, how do I treat children as grid cells?

Tags: css

I have a menu structure

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    menu item
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If I set the outer menu item display: grid by default the cells will be just the top 'li'. How can I flatten the structure making all the 'li' items grid cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare intermediate elements as "not even there" with `display: contents` (see [article on bitsofco.de](https://bitsofco.de/how-display-contents-works/)) which visually flatten sublists because if child `li` and grandchild `ul` aren't grid items anymore, then text node and grand-grand-child `li` are now the grid items BUT it causes [huge problems related to semantics and accessibility](http://adrianroselli.com/2018/05/display-contents-is-not-a-css-reset.html) as it's implemented in browsers for now.
E.g. you shouldn't in the first place flatten visually something that is hierarchical in your HTML code.

CSS solution: **[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pOPMRq)**

```css
.menu_outer {
  display: grid;
  max-width: 20rem;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.menu_outer > li,
.menu_outer .menu {
  display: contents;
}

.menu > li {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

/* styling */
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu_outer">
  <li>
    menu item
    <ul class="menu">
      <li>menu item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Support of [display: contents](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) is partial: Firefox (accessible in incoming versions), Chrome and Safari (buggy under the hood) but not Edge and lol@IE

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`.menu li { display: grid; }`